# Error occurs when linking libboost_python

Tags: python, boost, ld

I want to build this [openNERO](http://code.google.com/p/opennero/) for myself. According to its [building tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/opennero/wiki/BuildingOpenNero), I also build Boost 1.48 with python 2.7.2. With Boost, openNERO is compiled successfully. But when it try to link, `ld` complains that

```
CMakeFiles/OpenNERO.dir/scripting/scripting.cpp.o: In function `initOpenNero':
~/svn/opennero/trunk/source/scripting/scripting.cpp:21: undefined reference to `boost::python::detail::init_module(char const*, void (*)())'
/usr/local/lib/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyModule_Create2'
/usr/local/lib/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyBytes_AsString'
/usr/local/lib/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyBytes_Size'
/usr/local/lib/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `_PyUnicode_AsString'
/usr/local/lib/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyUnicode_InternFromString'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone give hints for me on this issue? Thank you~

**UPDATE 1:** [Removed]

**UPDATE 2:** Thanks for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5810101/688080). I use `nm` to check the signature of `init_module`, yet it prints:

```
$nm libboost_python.so.1.48.0 |c++filt|grep init_module
0002e710 T boost::python::detail::init_module(PyModuleDef&, void (*)())
```

Here is the snippet from the [source file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/boost/python/module_init.hpp):

```
#  if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000
BOOST_PYTHON_DECL PyObject* init_module(PyModuleDef&, void(*)());
#  else
BOOST_PYTHON_DECL PyObject* init_module(char const* name, void(*)());
#  endif
```

So it is of Python 3.x. But I did build Boost with parameter `--with-python-version=2.7`. Moreover, I use `update-alternatives` to choose Python 2.7. So why is the `PY_VERSION_HEX` still not correct?

Comment: Can you add your ld command to the question? It's difficult to determine what's going wrong from just the errors.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess I cannot find the `ld` command in the cmake-generated makefile. I update my post with the file content.

Comment: Try running `make -n` and see if it displays the `ld` command in the output.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess, this time I use nm and get closer to where the problem is. Please see my update 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember I first built boost with python 3.2, so I deleted all the files generated and rebuilt boost again. This time everything is correct. It seems that the older files will not be overwritten.