# Linker error with libboost_python-py34 on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I must be making some simple mistake trying to use boost-python on Ubuntu Linux 15.04 (Vivid Vervet), with the libboost-python1.55-dev package installed.

I'm trying to build a simple test file like so:

```
$ g++ -o conftest -Wall -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.4m  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_python-py34 -lpython3.4m conftest.cc
```

But that gives me this linker error:

```
/tmp/ccxkW5XR.o: In function `PyInit_test':
conftest.cc:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `boost::python::detail::init_module(PyModuleDef&, void (*)())'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But that symbol really does seem to exist:

```
$ nm -D --demangle /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so | grep "init_module"
0000000000033ac0 T boost::python::detail::init_module(PyModuleDef&, void (*)())
```

This is the very simple test code that I'm building,  based on a config test used by the AX_BOOST_PYTHON autoconf macro:

```
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test) { throw "Boost::Python test."; }

int
main ()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check this similar question  : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810101/undefined-boost-python-symbol-boostpythondetailinit-module

Comment: Sorry, though that looks similar, I don't think it's quite the same problem. The solution in that case seems to have been to install the python-dev package, but I have that installed already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that stuck out to me in your compiler invocation is that you've listed the libraries before the source file that uses them on the command line.

This will usually work anyway with shared libraries, but isn't strictly correct.  For instance, it'll break if you're using static libraris, since only the objects from the archive needed to satisfy symbols from things earlier in the command line are included.  But it seems to make a difference here, even though we're using shared libraries:

```sh
$ g++ -o conftest -Wall -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.4m  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_python-py34 -lpython3.4m conftest.cc
/tmp/ccj8Znlk.o: In function `PyInit_test':
conftest.cc:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `boost::python::detail::init_module(PyModuleDef&, void (*)())'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$ g++ -o conftest -Wall -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.4m  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu conftest.cc -lboost_python-py34 -lpython3.4m
$ ldd conftest | grep python
    libboost_python-py34.so.1.55.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so.1.55.0 (0x00007f6291003000)
    libpython3.4m.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 (0x00007f62909c2000)
```

The second `g++` invocation succeeds and produces a correctly linked executable.

Comment: Many thanks. Yes, it looks like the source file must be after the CFLAGS (-I options) but before the linker flags (-L and -l). Unfortunately, that's not what the AC_LINK_IFELSE autoconf macro generates. Googling led me to someone else who had a similar problem, but not with boost: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-autoconf/2013-10/msg00005.html

Comment: So I'm going to investigate if the use of LDFLAGS in the boost autoconf macros is the problem: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-autoconf/2013-10/msg00009.html

Comment: Interestingly (because it's you), jhbuild seems to set LDFLAGS to provide the "-L/opt/gnome" prefix. Maybe it should use LIBS?

Comment: It's been a while since I've had to deal with autoconf/automake, but IIRC they split `LDFLAGS` / `LIBS` exactly for this purpose: you want the libraries at the end of the command line, and other flags earlier.

Comment: For anybody else having exactly the same problem with AX_BOOST_PYTHON(): This is how I fixed it: https://git.gnome.org/browse/glom/commit/?id=8eb81378e85a6ff6b4f51f307a423b0ad2f690b9 . I filed a bug about AX_PYTHON_DEVEL, so if they fix it there then the change to AX_BOOST_PYTHON might not be necessary in the future: https://savannah.gnu.org/patch/?8701